# Is it conceptually right to create a rest API using the post for every request?

Tags: node.js, rest, https, api-design

I'm developing a rest API that, once you've bought a paid plan and received an apiKey, you can create a maximum of a certain number of apps depending on the paid plan chosen. I'm using node.js and to handle requests I'm using HTTPS module like this:

```
https.createServer(options, (req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200);
    req.on('data', function (data) {

        let command = data.toString();

        var cmd = utils.getCommand(command);
        var cmdResult = "";

        switch (cmd.method) {
            case 'SIGNIN':
                cmdResult = auth.signin(cmd.parameters[0], cmd.parameters[1], cmd.parameters[2]);
                break;
            case 'LOGIN':
                cmdResult = auth.login(cmd.parameters[0], cmd.parameters[1], cmd.parameters[2]);
                break;
        }

        res.end(result.getResult(cmdResult));
    });
}).listen(11200);
```

**For debugging I'm using curl like this:**

```
curl -X POST 'SIGNIN|username|password|apikey' https://mycurrentipaddress:11200
```

*The above command performs a signin to add a new app that using the API; the authentication work with the apiKey*

the API will offer an authentication service, a noSQL DB based on JSON and push notifications.

**Was my idea and its current realization conceptually correct? or it doesn't make sense?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that isn't REST, you should read [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/02/best-practices-for-rest-api-design/) for a better understanding of that pattern.

That doesn't mean it won't work, but it's not a conventional pattern, which I think is what you're looking for.

There are any number of tutorials on the internet on how to write a *RESTful* API, just take the time to follow some. Also, I'd also **strongly** suggest starting with a framework like [ExpressJS](https://expressjs.com/) rather than the Node standard libraries, you'll have plenty of opportunity to learn those in the future, starting with a framework is a much better path for learning, imo.